# Asset instance from a URL to get location

Tags: iphone, ios5, cllocation, alassetslibrary

I am trying to get location co-ordinates of a saved photo. I have the URL by:

```
NSURL *photoUrl = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL];
```

and now I am trying to use

> "valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyLocation"

which works on an ALAsset object.

How do I get an ALAsset object instance from the photoURL?

I am trying to avoid the "assetForURL" with the result/failure blocks.

thanks,
Tarak

Answer (score 0):

The only way to get an ALAsset is using the assetForURL: blocks.

You could enumerate all the ALAssets in the library and match them to the NSURL you got from the saved photo.